# SharePoint Cascading Dropdown with CAML query that filters one of the choices

Tags: sharepoint, caml

I have made a cascading dropdown form using http://spservices.codeplex.com but want to add a filter to the third cascading dropdown. So SPServices have a function called CAMLQuery where I can add this filter but I want the filter to be specified with the value from the top dropdown on the form.

One example that is given on the page is:

```
            CAMLQuery: "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Text'>Active</Value></Eq>"
```

I want this Status column to get its value from the choice selected on of the fields on the form. Is this possible and how would I write that?

---

Edit: I am trying to make an asset list with cascading choices to find the right asset after picking unit and department. 
Code example after trying the below answer and not getting anything coming up in the "Asset" chooser. There are two lists, one containing Units and Departments and one containing the assets with a Department and Unit key to filter with.
If I replace the "dynamic" queries with a static one such as:

```
CAMLQuery: "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Unit'/><Value Type='Text'>Unit 1</Value></Eq>"
```

the assets appear filtered for that unit. Current code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../Hidden/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../Hidden/jquery.SPServices-0.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var sCamlQuery = "";

$(document).ready(function() {
    $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
        relationshipList: "Departments",
        relationshipListParentColumn: "Unit",
        relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
        parentColumn: "Unit",
        childColumn: "Department",
        completefunc: function() {
        sCamlQuery = "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Unit'/><Value Type='Text'>" + $("select[title='Unit']").attr("spcascadedropdown_selected_") + "</Value></Eq>";
        }
    });
        $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
        relationshipList: "Asset Database",
        relationshipListParentColumn: "Department",
        relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
        parentColumn: "Department",
        childColumn: "Asset",
        CAMLQuery: sCamlQuery
    });

});
```

The HTML:

```
<tr>
<td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
    <H3 class="ms-standardheader"><nobr>Unit</nobr></H3>
</td>
<td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
    <span dir="none">
        <select name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$g_c482307d_1a31_4129_8a0a_376d70562746$ff3_1$ctl00$Lookup" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_c482307d_1a31_4129_8a0a_376d70562746_ff3_1_ctl00_Lookup" title="Unit">
            <option selected="selected" value="0">(None)</option>
            <option value="1">Unit 1</option>
            <option value="2">Unit 2</option>
        </select>
    </span>¨
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
    <H3 class="ms-standardheader"><nobr>Department</nobr></H3>
</td>
<td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
    <span dir="none">
        <select name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$g_c482307d_1a31_4129_8a0a_376d70562746$ff4_1$ctl00$Lookup" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_c482307d_1a31_4129_8a0a_376d70562746_ff4_1_ctl00_Lookup" title="Department">
            <option selected="selected" value="0">(None)</option>
            <option value="5">Administration</option>
            <option value="4">IT</option>
            <option value="1">Kitchen</option>
            <option value="2">Production</option>
            <option value="7">Production</option>
            <option value="6">Sales</option>
            <option value="3">Warehouse</option>
        </select>
    </span>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>    
<td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
    <H3 class="ms-standardheader"><nobr>Asset</nobr></H3>
</td>
<td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
    <span dir="none">
        <select name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$g_c482307d_1a31_4129_8a0a_376d70562746$ff5_1$ctl00$Lookup" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_c482307d_1a31_4129_8a0a_376d70562746_ff5_1_ctl00_Lookup" title="Asset">
            <option selected="selected" value="0">(None)</option>
            <option value="3">Computer</option>
            <option value="2">Copy machine</option>
            <option value="1">Dishwasher</option>
            <option value="5">Dishwasher</option>
            <option value="4">Oven</option>
        </select>
    </span>
</td>
</tr>
```

Verifying function:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../Hidden/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../Hidden/jquery.SPServices-0.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var sCamlQuery = "";

$(document).ready(function() {

    $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
        relationshipList: "Departments",
        relationshipListParentColumn: "Unit",
        relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
        parentColumn: "Unit",
        childColumn: "Department",
        completefunc: function() {
        sCamlQuery = window.alert("completefunc");//"<Eq><FieldRef Name='Unit'/><Value Type='Text'>"+ $("select[title='Unit'] option:selected").text() +"</Value></Eq>";
                                }
    });

        $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
        relationshipList: "Asset Database",
        relationshipListParentColumn: "Department",
        relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
        parentColumn: "Department",
        childColumn: "Asset",
        CAMLQuery: sCamlQuery
    });

});
</script>
```

**Departments list:**

*Title*  *Unit*

IT       Unit1

Sales    Unit1

IT       Unit2

Sales    Unit2

**Asset Database:**

*Title*  *Department* *Unit*

Asset1    IT    Unit1

Asset2    IT     Unit2

David

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation for [SPCascadeDropdowns](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns), you have the ability to specify a callback function that executes whenever the parent column changes. This seems like exactly the hook you need to wire up what you're asking for.

You posted no code samples, so I'll just have to make something up. Their demo page uses Region, State and City, so let's play with that.

If I wanted to add a filter to "City" based on the selected value of "Region", I might use this:

```
var sCamlQuery = "";

// Cascade definition for State dropdown
$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
    relationshipList: "States",
    relationshipListParentColumn: "Region",
    relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
    relationshipListSortColumn: "Title",
    parentColumn: "Region",
    childColumn: "State" 
    completefunc: function() {
        sCamlQuery = "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Text'>" + $("select[title='Region'] option:selected").text() + "</Value></Eq>";
    })
});

// Cascade definition for City dropdown
$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
    relationshipList: "Cities",
    relationshipListParentColumn: "State",
    relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
    parentColumn: "State",
    childColumn: "City",
    CAMLQuery: sCamlQuery
});
```

That's a pretty naive jQuery selector to find the SELECT element (looking at the TITLE attribute), but you should get the idea. The anonymous function defined for `completefunc` should run whenever the parent column ("Region") is changed, and updates the value of the global var `sCamlQuery`. When the "City" cascade runs, it will use the generated CAML query.

---

Edit: Updated example to better match the OP scenario. When the top-most cascade runs ("Region"), it will trigger the `completefunc` anonymous method in the "State" cascade. This sets the value of the `sCamlQuery` variable, and will be used when the "City" cascade runs.

---

Edit #2: Updated sample code to use a more general-purpose jQuery selector; it will retrieve the text value of the selected `OPTION`. If you want the `OPTION` **value** instead, you can simplify it to be: `$("select[title='Region']").val()`

Comment: Thank you for your response! I think I am getting close, but it is still not filtering out really and I guess it is because I am looking at a cascade that is above the one I am working with.
If you are looking at the examples on the site I am basically wanting to filter with the selected Country rather than the City in your example.

Comment: I think I understand what you're asking for. The value of "Region" should determine the CAML query that runs for "City". I've updated my answer to reflect that scenario.

Comment: Nearly.. If I write the CAML myself it works but when using your new code it doesnt bring up any values at all. 
If I write this static:
    CAMLQuery: "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Unit'/><Value Type='Text'>RP</Value></Eq>" it works but if using yours like:
    <Eq><FieldRef Name='Unit'/><Value Type='Text'>" + $("select[title='Unit']").attr("spcascadedropdown_selected_") + "</Value></Eq>
nothing comes up. So would your query bring up the same as my "static" one? I am trying to query the Unit I pick in the above and use in the bottom filter. As the example they are different lists, does it matter?

Comment: Without having a code example, I'm not sure what is going to work in your particular instance. I assume the issue is the jQuery selector for retrieving the selected "Unit" value. If you don't already use them, get [Mozilla Firefox](http://mozilla.com/) and an extension called [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). Load up your page and turn on the Firebug panel. In Firebug's "Console" tab, you can execute jQuery queries and see what they return. Run your selector using "jQuery" instead of "$": `jQuery("select[title='Unit']").attr("spcascadedropdown_selected_")`. See what value (if any) comes back.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to do this but it comes up as "undefined". Not sure if I am doing it wrong as it is the first time I try to run commands in the console. I pasted more information and the code example if that will help you, help me ;)

Comment: No, it sounds like you're doing it right. If the query comes back as `undefined`, it means we're not using the right query. I reviewed your code, but what will help is if you can post the HTML for your Unit dropdown menu. Then we can write the correct jQuery selector to grab its value.

Comment: Hey, hope you had a good weekend and thanks for coming back to have a go at this once again. I have posted the html from the NewForm.aspx file for you.

Comment: Almost there... that's the ASPX source code, but the jQuery has to be written against the rendered HTML output. Can you load up the page in your browser and "View Source" then paste the equivalent section?

Comment: My answer has been updated. If you want to retrieve the Unit value (i.e. "1" or "2"), use `$("select[title='Unit']").val()`. If you want the Unit text (i.e. "Unit 1" or "Unit 2") you'd use `$("select[title='Unit'] option:selected").text()`. I highly recommend you read up on [jQuery usage](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works "jQuery - How jQuery Works") -- it's an awesome product and can make your life much easier.

Comment: Thanks, now I can run the query in command windows in Firebug to get the result but still nothing shows up in the select box. 

completefunc: function() {
      sCamlQuery = "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Unit'/><Value Type='Text'>" + $("select[title='Unit'] option:selected").text() + "</Value></Eq>";
            }

Comment: Hmm. Verify that `completefunc` actually runs. Comment out the assignment for `sCamlQuery` and add `window.alert("Completefunc");`, then select a value for Unit and see if you see the alert box pop up. Maybe there's some problem with the documentation for the Cascade component.

Comment: A window pops open when the page has loaded but it says only "completefunc" is that right? Nothing after that i.e nothing when I select a unit.

Comment: I added the verify bits below my question in case I did it wrong. Thank you for your patience assisting me here.

Comment: No, the declaration of `sCamlQuery` should remain the same. Comment out the the **assignment** of the variable further down. In that same spot is where you put the `window.alert` line. What we're testing is that when the Unit dropdown gets changed, that the code specified in `completefunc` actually gets fired.

Comment: Apologies for my lack of experience. I adjusted and received the result of a popup whenever I change the unit dropdown. Can we somehow get it to display the value that we are picking in case it comes out slightly different to the value we want, maybe extra spaces or something?
I was thinking maybe it works just not finding any results because the filter is slightly off?

Comment: Yes, and maybe. Now that we know the code fires, uncomment the `sCamlQuery` assignment. Move the `window.alert` line **below** the assignment line, and change it to be: `window.alert(sCamlQuery);`. Probably should have done that to begin with, but one step at a time, right? This will pop up the exact value of the CAML query.

Comment: It looks correct. How can we verify that it is what the bottom section gets?

Comment: We verified the value of `sCamlQuery`, so it should be getting that value. You've verified the query actually works if you take the value that gets alerted and use it to make a static query?

Comment: yes, that works. Something must be going wrong when doing CAMLQuery: sCamlQuery. Do we run that correctly?

Comment: http://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/252607 Interesting. So we are fighting an impossible fight. I am now going to try the jquery path as Captain is doing...

Comment: Wow.. really having no luck with this. How would you go about tackling this issue?

Comment: This has exceeded my expertise. Without downloading the SPServices component and building a test app, I'm afraid I can't help. Maybe you can get some assistance from the forum to which you linked?

Comment: Thanks for giving this a try none the less. Do you have a paypal account I can treat you to a lunch?

Comment: Nonsense... I participate to help people. Sorry I couldn't help you more than I did. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

David:

You really should have asked this on the [SPServices site in the Discussions](http://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions) to start with!

What you are showing in your code above isn't necessary. If you make the two calls to SPCascadeDropdowns in the order you show, then you don't need

```
CAMLQuery: "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Unit'/><Value Type='Text'>Unit 1</Value></Eq>"
```

That's how the cascading works. The first call will limit the Departments to those that are in the selected Unit on selection of Unit. The second call will limit the Assets to those that are in the selected Department on selection of Department.

If you aren't getting the results you expect, then your relationshipLists may not have the values in them that you need.

M.

Edit based on additional info about the list contents:

It's definitely a data problem. You are combining relationships in the Department list and the Assets list. You should have these lists:

- Departments -- Each Department in the
  list exactly once.
- Units -- Each Unit
  in the list exactly once, with a
  column as a lookup to Title in
  Department indicating that Unit's
  Department.
- Assets -- Each Asset in
  the list exactly once, with a column
  as a lookup to Title in Units
  indicating that Asset's Unit.

This makes your lists truly relational and then the calls to SPCascadeDropdowns will do what you want, just as in the example in the docs for Country/Region/State/City.

Comment: Hello Marc,
Thank you for answering my question and helping out. I appreciate that I should have left this on SPServices site but I found that you had already answered that this was not possible in the current implementation.

The problem I have is that if I do what you are suggesting I am getting duplicate Departments as the Units are very similar to each other. So that is why I need to filter the Departments on the unit Column to make sure I get the assets belonging to that Department in that unit and not another unit.

Comment: That still sounds like a data issue. Do you have multiple Departments within one Unit with the same name?

Comment: Hello Marc, apologies... I am not getting duplicate departments rather I am getting assets belonging to a department in another unit. So it is cascading as it should but as there is for example a dishwasher in both unit 1 and unit 2 it shows up in the Assets list. It is only filtering on the departments in the last section.

Comment: OK, I still think it sounds like a data issue, then, not a code issue. Can you give any data examples?

Comment: hello Marc,
I have added an example of the lists above. As you can see the second cascade step will not take notice of the Unit column in the Assets Database list.

Comment: Dear Marc,

The problem with this is that there wont be a unit with only one department, so I cannot have the Units exactly once resulting in duplicates in that dropdown (IT, Sales, Finance will result in Unit 1 written three times).
Also as it is only filtering on the Unit all assets belonging to all departments in that unit will be listed i.e overload in our case.
My trial above with the "dynamic" CAML will (if functional) only show me the assets in the IT department in Unit 1.

Thank you for your support so far!

Comment: I'm going to stick with it being a data thing. While it's possible that there are two units named Unit 1 (one in IT and one in Sales), I would bet that they don't both own the exact same assets. Rememeber that just because two items have the same Title, it doesn't mean that they are the same item.

Comment: BTW, the filtering that you keep trying isn't going to work in any case, as it's not the way the function is written. The CAML filter is applied only on setup.